# E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1

Tags: android, android-studio

Everytime I test my APP on AndroidStudio I get this error message.

[image]

My APP works fine, but I am a little confused/curious about what this error means.

Even when I google for `GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator` I find 4 unrelated results (they name the Class but are not trying to fix it).

What this error message means?

Comment: What android SDK are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The library is logging an issue. Since you aren't seeing an issue with your app, then it's okay to ignore the message. You can set a Logcat filter to ignore the tag  `eglCodecCommon`.

The library causing the issue is OpenGl, a graphics library for Android. If you're interested, here is a link to the source code throwing the error: https://android.googlesource.com/device/generic/goldfish-opengl/+/refs/heads/master/shared/OpenglCodecCommon/goldfish_address_space_android.impl#400

Comment: This link is broken.

Comment: Looks like the file was deleted or moved. There is a very similar file and log message here https://android.googlesource.com/device/generic/goldfish-opengl/+/refs/heads/master/shared/GoldfishAddressSpace/include/goldfish_address_space_android.impl#436

Comment: Looks like this error doesn't show in API level 26 and below.